# Deployment process for deploying nodejs application to production using webpack

Tags: node.js, sdlc, webpack

I'm trying to work out what the correct process for deploying a nodejs application to a production environment should me, using webpack.

If this was a standard Java/Maven project I might do something like:

`mvn clean install -Pdeploy-production`

where the `mvn install` compiles the application, and the additional `deploy-production` profile uses a maven plugin to deploy it to our production environment and do whatever else.

I've been looking at tutorials like [this one](https://alejandronapoles.com/2016/09/29/simple-production-environment-with-webpack-and-express/), or [this one](https://github.com/dmachat/angular-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Deploy-to-production).

In the first tutorial, he suggests something like this:

```
"script": {
    "start": "babel-node server-es6.js"
    "build:server": "babel server-es6.js --out-file server.js"
    "build:client": "webpack -p --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress"
}
```

Where essentially he provides two build scripts, and then a command to start the server running.

However, this doesn't explain how I actually get the code on to the production server and start it running.

As far as I see I have two options:

- On the production environment checkout the source code, and run the build scripts there and start a node process.
- Run the production build scripts in my development environment and SCP the dist folder to the production environment, and start a process there.

Can you point me in the right direction about what the best way to do this is?

Comment: How do you define "best?"  The answer to that will probably go a long way towards guiding you in the right direction.  Note that your answer should be pragmatic, specific and requirements-driven, not merely a tautology like "best practice."

Answer (score 2):

The deployment process depends on your node.js application code base. If you use ES6/TypeScript, then you should transpile the code into ES5 with a help of a babel/tsc. You don't need webpack for server applications.

Your production environment should execute the following flow:

1. Check out the existing source code
2. Run `npm install`
3. Build/transpile sources if needed (e.g. using TypeScript/ES6); this can be included in `package.json` as a post-install script
4. Run `npm start`

It is a good solution to have your dependencies and main build/run scripts in a `package.json` configuration file.

There are also some handy libraries for managing node.js processes on linux (e.g. https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).